# Generating acronyms using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

This code below with its function to generate acronyms was extracted from Stanford Uni's lecture notes. The code checks for every character and correctly handles strings that have leading, trailing, or multiple spaces, or even hyphens. However, I have difficulty understanding a line of code.

```
function acronym(str) {
   let result = "";
   let inWord = false;
   for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      let ch = str.charAt(i);
      if (isLetter(ch)) {
         if (!inWord) result += ch;
         inWord = true;
      } else {
         inWord = false;
      }
   }
   return result;
}

function isLetter(ch) {
   return ch.length === 1 &&
          ALPHABET.indexOf(ch.toUpperCase()) !== -1;
}
```

As shown in the code above, I'm not quite sure how the "inWord" variable works. I'm not sure how it sets word boundaries that are indicated by sequences of nonletters. If you don't mind, can someone please enlighten me?

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The `inWord` variable is basically a flag as it loops through each character of the string and indicates whether it is inside of a word or not, as determined by the result of the `isLetter` function. If that returns false, then `inWord` will change to false. If it returns true and it is the first iteration, it will store the letter in the result and set the flag. If it is the 2nd iteration, the flag will be true so it won't store the letter until you are on the next word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code tries to make an acronym, i.e. take the first letter of every word to create to create a new word.

Translation of the loop:

- If the current character is a letter check if boolean flag is false
- If the boolean is false, add the character to the current acronym value
- Set the boolean flag to true, so the other letters of the word will not be executed until a separator is found
- Start from step 1 when a separator is found (non-alphabetic character).

So basically it just aggregates the first letters of every word into a new string.

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to get some idea around it. But i'm still a little confused with the boolean flag. In the if statement that says (!inWord), does it mean if boolean flag is false (i.e. inWord = true in this case)?

Comment: It says 'if false' then 'set the boolean flag to true after performing the concatenation of the current letter to the current acronym value, so that the concatenation doesn't happen anymore for the consequent letters of the current word'. I don't like this kind of code, it seems typical for schools / universities, but it's untransparent and messy. Much more readable would it be to add a few function calls although you could dispute that there is some performance tradeoff.

Comment: I got it. Thank you!